# Approximation theorem for measures - proof unclear

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

The following is from Achim Klenke - "Probability Theory" p. 28, Theorem 1.65 (ii):

Let $\mathcal{A}\subset 2^{\Omega}$ be a semiring and let $\mu$ be a measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ that is $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{A}$.

For any $\mathcal{A}\in\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ with $\mu(A)<\infty$ and any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and mutually disjoint sets $A_1, ..., A_n\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(A\Delta \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k)<\epsilon$.

The proof starts as follows:

As $\mu$ and the outer measure $\mu^*$ coincide on $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ and since $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is finite, by the very definition of $\mu^*$ there exists a covering $B_1,...\in\mathcal{A}$ of $A$ such that 
$\mu(A)\le \sum^\infty_{i=1}\mu(B_i) -\epsilon/2$

Here I think we need the construction of the outer measure, which is a lemma in my book, but is equivalent to this: [Outer measure construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Method_I)

So in the proof the epsilon property of the infimum is used and it should start like this

$\mu^*(A)\le \sum^\infty_{i=1}\mu(B_i) -\epsilon/2$

Now if the outer measure conincides on $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ it does so on its generator. But the problem is, that $A$ is not necessarily in $\mathcal{A}$, hence the outer measures on $\mathcal{A}$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ don't have to be equal. If I were to take a cover from $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ the outer measure is smaller or equal than that on just $\mathcal{A}$.

Why can I take a cover in $\mathcal{A}$ which is guaranteed to satisfy the inequality?